# "Iteration ID" for a CustomVision Project (for use in MSFlow action)?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm building an MSFlow which sends a SharePoint pic lib pic to a just-trained CustomVision Classifier, which then sends back a label (eg "Green", "Red", etc);

Challenges:

- My MSFlow "CustomVision" action is failing, stating "there's no default iteration for this project. please provide an Iteration ID"
- There is *nowhere* on the CustomVision project's settings page which displays this IterationID !

How / where to find this iteration ID (appears to be a GUID) ???

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the IterationID can be found as follows:

Browse to your custom vision projects page URL 
(eg https://www.customvision.ai/projects)
=> browser will display a set of "tiles" - one for each of your existing projects;

Navigate (click) on your particular project for which you seek the IterationID; 
=> browser will redirect to the "manage" page (note: defaults to Training Images page) for your project; 
It will look something like this: 
`https://www.customvision.ai/projects/<project GUID here>#/manage`

Navigate (click) on the *Performance* tab of this project
=> browser will direct to the "performance" page, something like this: 
`https://www.customvision.ai/projects/<project GUID here>#/performance`

Note: all of the "iterations" (ie training iterations) will be tabbed along the left side

Select the (training) iteration you wish to use as the "web service" for actually classifiying incoming images; 
=> browser will display details/metrics for that (training) iteration

Click on the "PredictionURL" tab in the upper left region of the page
=> a pop-up window will display all the settings-related data you'll need to consume the underlying web service ("API") wrapped around this classifier!

In particular, you'll see 2 different URLs:

- For ImageURL-as-input: 
  `https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/<projectGUIDhere>/url?iterationId=`**g9fc4e82-3f95-4ec1-acf2-9b12bba2b409**
- For ImageFILE-as-input: 
  `https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/<projectGUIDhere>/image?iterationId=`**g9fc4e82-3f95-4ec1-acf2-9b12bba2b409**

No matter *which* URL you inspect, you'll see the *same* value for IterationID - and there you have it!

Copy & paste this IterationID GUID into your MSFlow CustomVision Action, and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

In the custom vision portal [home](https://www.customvision.ai), Select the project you are using, then select the Performance Tab. On the left side of the page you would see Iterations. Select the Iteration that you want and select Prediction URL. This will open a new dialog which gives the URL's for image URL and image file. In this URL the iteration id is a parameter that is passed, Copy the id and use it in your application.

[image]

If you choose any iteration as default the iteration id would not be required in the image URL.